# Twitter Search API not returning Quoted Tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I am calling the twitter search API

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

My search term is anything from a particular account (mine).

It is returning tweets, and retweets, but is not returning quoted tweets.

Can anyone offer any advice on this?

Comment: Just to add to this, if I then retweet the quoted tweet, it comes through as a quoted tweet... is this an issue at twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the only way to get quoted Tweets is through the Account Activity API when tracking a specific @handle.

Which means it is no good for my use case!! :(